# Commerce catalog sorted by taxonomy term

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, commerce

I have a commerce shop with a bunch of products sorted by taxonomy terms with descriptions. Each product display is tagged with one category.
Now I want to display them in on view, sorted by the taxonomy terms.

It should look like this:

```
Category1
  Description

  Product1
  Product2

Category2
  Description

  Product3
  Product4
```

I read about some solutions but they required the use of the table formatter, but thats no solution because in need to display node teasers to use the add to cart widget. What is the easiest way to achieve this?
I'm not afraid of coding but have no experience with views.

Greetings MrPinkey

Comment: did you try group by taxonomy term id and than override views rows template to output term description?

Comment: Thank you! It works, just need to edit some theme files to add the description and remove the <h3> tags.

Comment: Not at all, upvote plz :)